# Symfony/Process cant run sh script from directory

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have some script: `/home/user/project/deploy.sh`
I trying to run with Symfony/Process component from php handler in another directory:

```
$process = new Process(['./deploy.sh']);
    $process->setWorkingDirectory('/home/user/project');
    $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
        echo $buffer;
});
```

But I got an error:

> The provided cwd "/home/user/project" does not exist.

This folder exists and symfony handler ran as correct user which have correct permissions to this folder. What is the correct way to run this script from another folder?

Comment: Maybe try $process->setWorkingDirectory(getcwd());

Comment: getcwd() - get current directory... php  handler and sh script in different directories
I need setWorkingDirectory from one dir to another

Comment: does the process also have the correct permissions to access /home and /home/user as well? php may also be configured to limit the access to some basedir, to which the home directory may not belong?

Answer (score 3):

Just for debugging purposes test code below.

```
$process = new Process(['/home/user/project/bin/console', '--version']);
$process->run();
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
echo $process->getOutput();
```

If it does work then try:

- `new Process(['/home/user/project/deploy.sh']);`
- `new Process(['sh /home/user/project/deploy.sh']);`
- `Process::fromShellCommandline('/home/user/project/deploy.sh');`

You may need to use the full path to `sh` since the webserver uses a different user and a `PATH` variable.